# How to Share Images from Browser to Android Native Apps?

Tags: android, image, android-intent

I'm looking for ways to share images from web browser in android. Either by pasting a link to load target image(not as a thumbnail on the left that usual comes from meta), or directly sending the image through share.

I've used Chrome's Web Share API but it only gives options to share title, text and url. If there is an image in this url as a meta, it's loading as a thumbnail on the left. But I need to share the actual image directly. Please help.

Comment: Hi, have you got the solution?

Comment: HI @Alankar, I didn't get any solution yet. We've let the users download from the browser and share directly from device gallery. But I hope this is not a lost cause though!

Comment: Hi @bhanu, I have got the solution. 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63253187/web-share-api-is-not-working-for-images-saved-on-server/63614800#63614800